# set session cookie returned by sakai new session web service

Tags: web-services, rest, cookies, restful-authentication, sakai

I am logging into sakai using web service(/direct/session/new) but it's not saving the sessionId in cookie. So I was unable to continue the session.

Sakai Mobile App:
In our mobile app, Session is persisting if I invoke the same login web service from Titanium appcelerator http client.

SakaiPy(Python API):
This api using python's session.post which is able to set session cookie as per below code from the [file](https://github.com/willkara/SakaiPy/blob/master/SakaiPy/RequestGenerator.py).

```
session.post(self.baseURL+loginURL.format(connectionInfo['username'],connectionInfo['password']))
```

Can you please suggest same kind of functionality in JAVA.

Comment: Broken UR reference.